# kubectl jsonpath query and output multiple object values

Tags: kubernetes, formatting, kubectl, jsonpath

Below is my output of `kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces`:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
            "kind": "Deployment",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "downscaler/uptime": "Mon-Fri 07:00-23:59 Australia/Sydney",
                "name": "actiontest-v2.0.9",
                "namespace": "actiontest",
            },
            "spec": {
        ......
        ......
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
            "kind": "Deployment",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "downscaler/uptime": "Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney",
                "name": "anotherapp-v0.1.10",
                "namespace": "anotherapp",
            },
            "spec": {
        ......
        ......
        }
}
```

I need to find the name of the deployment and its namespace if the annotation `"downscaler/uptime"` matches the value `"Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney"`. I am expecting an output like below:

```
deployment_name,namespace
```

If I am running below query against a single deployment, I get the required output.

```
#kubectl get deploy -n anotherapp -o jsonpath='{range .[*]}{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.downscaler/uptime=="Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney")].metadata.name}{","}{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.downscaler/uptime=="Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney")].metadata.namespace}{"\n"}'

anotherapp-v0.1.10,anotherapp
```

But when I run it against all namespaces, I am getting an output like below:

```
#kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .[*]}{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.downscaler/uptime=="Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney")].metadata.name}{","}{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.downscaler/uptime=="Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney")].metadata.namespace}{"\n"}'


actiontest-v2.0.9 anotherapp-v0.1.10, actiontest anotherapp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite short answer, however you can use this option:

```
kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(.metadata.annotations.downscaler/uptime=="Mon-Fri 07:00-21:00 Australia/Sydney")]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.metadata.namespace}{"\n"}'
```

What I changed is logic how to work with data:

First thing what happens is getting into `range` list of elements we need to work on, not everything. I used [filter expression - see Jsonpath notation - syntax elements](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html).

And once we have already filtered entities in the list, we can easily retrieve other fields we need.

Comment: That was awesome mate. Do you know where I can learn more about jsonpath/jq etc? Like some training?

Comment: [Kubernetes Documentation for JsonPath Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/).  Standard Proposal for JSONPath  [Stefan Goessner JsonPath implementation](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). Use Online tools  https://jsonpath.com/ for testing your jsonpath only

Comment: Sorry for that mate. I didn't know about the "accepting the answer" part. I'm gonna do it right away.